Why is my time computation not the same evolution curve as the complexity?
Lets say I have a certain number of schools and a certain number of students.
For each student i want to compute a new grade from their old grade using a random coefficient.
I use as much arrays as I have schools and they are all of size number of students per school.
The number of total students among all schools is always constant.
What I want to change is the number of schools.
So if we have more schools, we will have less students per school.
Since we always have the same number of students, and a computation per student, we will always have the same number of computations even when changing the number of schools.
So when the number of schools varies, the total computations should take the same time right ?
Well, wrong apparently. When I do my computations (i use the mean on many iterations each time so that i have a more meaningfull time computation) the number of time computation is not constant at all and increase with the number of schools.
Does someone have an explanation ?
public static Long changeNotesComputationTime(Random random, int nIterations, int nSchools, int nStudents) {
    long[] timePerIteration = new long[nIterations];
    int nStudentsPerSchool = nStudents / nSchools;
    for (int iIteration = 0; iIteration < nIterations; iIteration++) {
        System.out.println(iIteration + " iteration");
        long computationTime = 0;
        for (int iSchool = 0; iSchool < nSchools; iSchool++) {
            int[] gradesOfStudents = random.ints(nStudentsPerSchool, 0, 20).toArray();
            double coeff = random.nextDouble();
            int[] gradesChangedOfStudents = new int[nStudentsPerSchool];
            long startComputations = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int iStudent = 0; iStudent < nStudentsPerSchool; iStudent++) {
                gradesChangedOfStudents[iStudent] = (int) (gradesOfStudents[iStudent] * coeff);
            }
            long endComputations = System.currentTimeMillis();
            computationTime += endComputations - startComputations;
        }

        timePerIteration[iIteration] = computationTime;
    }
    return Arrays.stream(timePerIteration).sum() / nIterations;
}


    @Test
    public void Test() throws PerformanceException, IOException {
        final Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths
                .get(outputPathFolder, "ComputationTime.csv"), Charset.defaultCharset());

        final int nIterations = 100;
        final int nStudents = 10000000;

        writer.write(
                "number of schools; computation time [ms]\n");
        for (int nSchools = 5000000; nSchools < nStudents; nSchools += 500000) {
            writer.write(Long.toString(nSchools) + ";");
            writer.write(
                    Long.toString(Fixture.changeNotesComputationTime(random, nIterations, nSchools, nStudents))
                            + "\n");
        }
        writer.close();
    }

Here is the curve I obtain : 
edit : I know we can argue that the number of students may not be equal exactly each time since the number of students may not be divisible by the number of schools but in the real code I used i made sure it was the case and i still have an increasing curve

"So when the number of schools varies, the total computations should take the same time right ?" no, that assumption is wrong. You have an outer loop which effectively acts as a multiplier for the number of students, so...

but if the number of schools goes up, the number of students goes down, if i have 10 schools and 1 student par school it's the same number of computations as if I have 1 schools and 10 students par school, no ?

the number of internal loops increase with the number of schools and posted code is including this loop in the computation time (not sure if that is enough to explain the behavior - recommended to check How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java? and similar)

Incorrect branch prediction will probably explain this, especially with the number of schools you're using: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor

You should show your real code, where you made sure the numbers are divisible.

@user642308 Your 'edit' is presumably in response to Marce Puente's answer, but, the code as it is in this question introduces a massive 45% error due to the rounding issue. If you have 'made sure' that in the 'real code' it's fine, you should edit the question. The code snippets as provided result in the curve you provided and the explanation is that rounding error. We can't help you until that is eliminated as variable.

the error is very subtle, and it is related to the values you chose, in the first iteration you have:
nSchools = 5000000;
nStudentsPerSchool = 2;

in the second :
nSchools = 5500000;
nStudentsPerSchool = 1;

and in the following ones, the number of schools will continue to increase, but the number of students will continue to be “1”, that is the origin of the error.
nSchools = 6000000;
nStudentsPerSchool = 1;

nSchools = 6500000;
nStudentsPerSchool = 1;

....

To avoid this error, the number of students must be equal to or greater than the number of schools.

To give a little more context to this answer: The error is in the @Test case, not the actual snippet of code itself; integer division occurs, and the error results in -fewer loops-. Marce's discovery is that this error is extremely large; the very first iteration has 0 error, then the second iteration has a massive 45% error (45% fewer students), which slowly creeps back to 0% during the iterations. A sufficient explanation for the observed curve.
